# How to change iframe z-index from inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

There is an iframe. and in it a link going to 'about:blank'; I need to set this iframe's z-index to '-1' when i click this link; How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can z-index an iframe like that (in order to hide it below other elements), how about just hiding it by settings the CSS display to NONE ?

Comment: how can i do that from inside the iframe?

Comment: if the iframe is like `<iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" src="any.html"></iframe>`, do this from inside `$(parent.document.getElementById(window.name)).toggle(false);`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If what you need is to hide the iframe, add css display:none for the onclick event of the hyperlink

Inside document ready function,

```
$('a#your_hyperlink_id').click(function(){
$('iframe').css('display','none');
});
```